# How to sum two arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I made a DataFrame like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

occurrence = np.array([4, 5, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3])
year = np.array([1851,1852,1853,1854,1855,1856,1857])
disaster = {"occur":pd.Series(occur),"year":pd.Series(year)}
df =  pd.DataFrame(disaster)
```

Now I want to make a function so that, when I give two years, it will give me the sum of occurrences of those two years. If I put `1851` and `1852`, it will show me the occurrence is `9`.

I wrote a function like this, but it shows error:

```
def dist(s1,s2):
    return (sum (year>=s1 and year< s2))

print dist(s1,s2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're specifically wanting only a `numpy` approach, you'd do something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np

occurrence= np.array([4, 5, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3])
year = np.array([1851,1852,1853,1854,1855,1856,1857])

year1, year2 = 1851, 1852
mask = (year == year1) | (year == year2)
print occurrence[mask].sum()
```

Note that if you wanted the sum of all occurences between those two years, you'd do something more like:

```
mask = (year >= year1) & (year <= year2)
```

With `pandas`, the same approach still works, but as others have noted, there are more efficient ways of building the boolean mask with the `isin` method, if you're interested in just those two years (and not the interval between them).

Comment: i need all the values in between any two years, Thanks

Comment: @AlfradNobel - Then use the mask shown in the second code snippet. It's the same for pandas as it is for numpy.

Comment: if i want to write it as a function, then how can i do that ? can you please tell ?

Answer (score 4):

```
print(df.loc[df['year'].isin((1851,1852))]["occur"].sum())
```

Or:

```
 print(df.loc[df.year.isin((1851,1852))].occur.sum())
```

For a range of dates creating a list of ranges seems more efficient than using `&`:

```
df.loc[df.year.isin(range(s1, s2+1))].occur.sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&` instead of `and`. This means your function should be:

```
def dist(s1, s2):
    return df.occur[(df.year >= s1) & (df.year <= s2)].sum()
```

And then you have:

```
In [72]: dist(1851, 1852)
Out[72]: 9
```

Both `1851 <= df.year` and `df.year <= 1852` create a boolean Series. The Python `and` does not work with these objects as we want - it essentially calls `bool` on each Series and this causes the error. On the other hand, `&` will perform a element-wise and, returning `True` when both Series are `True`.

You might also find `isin()` useful for summing the values for a given list of dates. For example:

```
>>> df.occur[df.year.isin([1851, 1852])].sum()
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [21]: import numpy as np

In [22]: import pandas as pd

In [23]: occurrence= np.array([4, 5, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3])

In [24]: year = np.array([1851,1852,1853,1854,1855,1856,1857])

In [25]: my_func = lambda *l: sum([x[0] for x in zip(occurrence, year) if x[1] in l])

In [26]: my_func(1851, 1852)
Out[26]: 9

In [27]:
```

Comment: Note that this is rather inefficient for numpy arrays.  (Iteration through a numpy array is relatively slow at the python level compared to lists.)  For a small array, it won't matter much, but it will be needlessly slow and memory-inefficient for larger arrays.

Comment: Vor; your code only gives the sum of first and second year not the cumulative. like when i gave
my_func(1851, 1852) it gave 4 but it should be 13, thanks  a lot

Comment: Hi all, thanks a lot, but, i gave two years as an example. But i need sum of the values between any two years. s when i am running this code it gives me sum of two years not the the sum of all the values in between any two years